# Determinant is a quadratic form

Tags: determinant, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Let $H=\{A \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \ | \ A = A^\dagger := \overline{A}^t  \}$ be the real vector space of all hermitian $2 × 2$ complex matrices.

(a) Show that for all $A \in H$, $\text{det}(A)$ is real-valued.

Define $Q:H \to \mathbb{R}$, by $A \mapsto \text{det}(A)$.

(b) Show that $Q$ is a quadratic form, and calculate the signature of the
associated bilinear form $S_Q$.

Let be $U = \{A \in H : \text{Tr}(A) = 0 \} \subseteq H$.

(c) Find $U^\perp$ with respect to $S_Q$.

(d) Calculate the signature of $(S_Q)|_{U \times U} :  U \times U \to \mathbb{R}$.

For problem (a), my approach would be that the eigenvalues of hermitian matrices are real-valued. Since the determinant of a matrix $A$ can be represented as the product of the eigenvalues of $A$, the determinant is real-valued, because the factors are all real-valued.

Now I have a problem making a start with task (b), because I don't know how to define $Q$.
Could someone give me a hint on how to do this?
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Figure out what a generic hermitian matrix looks like, from definition (put complex unknowns in the matrix elements and see what the definition tells about them). Then, compute the determinant explicitly in real coordinates: you'll immediately see if it is a quadratic form or not (it actually is).

Comment: such a matrix is, with some real $r,s,x,y$  $$  \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
r & x+iy \\ 
x-iy & s \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$  What is the determinant for example?

Comment: meanwhile, it is convenient. to pick an order for $r,s,x,y$  and deal with the 4 by 4 matrix which is the Hessian of the quadratic form. If you have trouble completing the square, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: I think I have now been able to define Q and have also been able to calculate a corresponding matrix.
I would like to post it, but unfortunately I am too stupid to use MathJax.

Comment: I put a four by four matrix  with all entries zero. You may correct the entries to show your matrix

Comment: I have now managed to write down the matrix.
Since I am not quite familiar with latex yet, I need some time to answer.
I apologize for this.
I calculated the signature of the bilinear form by calculating the signature of the matrix(am I allowed to do it this way?).  The signature would be (0,2,2).

I have a question about (c)
Do I find the set U orthogonal by looking at the radical of U?